# Using Recursion to Calculate Powers in different ways

Tags: java, math, recursion

I was given a beginner assignment based on recursion to calculate the product of any given base and power.

My professor wanted us to use recursion to calculate this using three different methods..
I've done the first two with little problem, however the final recursive function is giving me grief.

(for method power4)

•   X^n =  ( X^ (n / 2)^2 if n > 0 and n is even

•   X^n =  X * ( X^ (n / 2)^2 if n > 0 and n is odd

**all I need to do is raise power4(x, (n/2)) to the power of 2**

I am not allowed to call the math class... I can't think of anyway to raise this function to the power of 2, any help would greatly be appreciated.

PS: I would prefer help or an explanation rather than just the answer if possible
Thanks.

I just need help with the method power4, power2 and power3 already work fine.
CODE:

```
    public int power2(int x, int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        answer = 1;

    else if (n > 0)
        answer = x * power2(x, (n - 1));

    return answer;
}

public int power3(int x, int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        answer = 1;

    else if(n % 2 == 0)
        answer = power3(x, (n/2)) * power3(x, (n/2));

    else
        answer = x * power3(x, (n/2)) * power3(x, (n/2));

    return answer;
}

public int power4(int x, int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        answer = 1;

//incomplete code from here down
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        answer = 

    else
        answer = x * 

    return answer;      
}
```

Comment: It should look like power3, only it also needs to then call power4 with the answer for x, and the n of 2.

Comment: Apply closing brackets for Method Power4 condition in your question

Comment: @OGLOKE: But what’s your problem? Why don’t you implement `power4` just as straightforward as `power3`?

Comment: @Holger because for some reason my professor thinks it would be fun for us to try and solve this problem in three different ways, even though method 3 and 4 are one in the same.

I think it must have something to do with the following question he has asked us to answer:
**How many multiplications will each of the functions power2, power3, power4 perform when computing 3^24 and 3^17? Do the theoretical calculations and modify the functions to count the results.**

Comment: @OGLOKE: They are not exactly the same, but still, you have a formula and the only thing to do is to rewrite `…^…` to `powerⁿ(…,…)` and `formula if condition` to `if(condition) formula;`. If the follow-up question is causing problems I don’t understand why you ask for the trivial function implementation instead for the follow-up question.

Comment: @Holger: I haven't yet reached the follow-up question, I am simply trying to write this method but can not figure out how to raise power4(x, (n/2)) to the power of 2. The follow up question I am not worried about, I only provided that because you asked why I not just implement power4 the same as power3, thanks for the help I am unclear of your comment "rewrite …^… to powerⁿ(…,…) and formula if condition to if(condition) formula;" however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raising a value to the power of two, a.k.a. squaring it, is simply multiplying it by itself.  However, DON'T multiply two recursive calls to the function - do something like

```
result = power4(x, n/2);
answer = result * result;
```

Then, if it's odd, multiply `answer` by `x`.

If you were to try doing this as `answer = power4(x, n/2) * power4(x, n/2);`, you'd be doubling the amount of work at each level of the recursion by calling the function twice, and completely undo the logarithmic run time.

By the way, are you sure one of your cases isn't supposed to be based on **x<sup>n</sup> = (x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n/2</sup>** or **x<sup>n</sup> = x*(x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n/2</sup>** for n even or odd, respectively?  As you've described it, it looks like power3 and power4 are the same.

Comment: @Holger No, doubling at **each level** of the recursion brings it back to linear time.

Comment: thanks pjs I believe you've solved my problem, and im positive my cases are how they are supposed to be, I've checked with my professor, I believe the whole point to this problem is to understand how recursion works and to see how much work it takes solving the same problem different ways using recursion. Thanks alot to everyone who provided some input it has been very helpful.

Comment: @Holger I disagree that it's not an issue, when I teach intro programming I use exactly this to introduce computational complexity and show how halving the problem at each recursive call leads to logarithmic run times as opposed to brute-force n repeated multiplications.  As for it being the same as the third variant, that's why I aded the question in my final paragraph.

Comment: @pjs: the question you have added now is exactly what the original task is about, it doesn’t matter whether it is `X^n = X^ (n/2)^2` or `X^n = X^2^(n/2)`. But of course, `result = power4(x*x, n/2);` would be the solution that *really* differs from solution 3…

Comment: @Holger Yup, I completely agree.  Hence the question.  I hope OGLOKE didn't misunderstand the instructor's specification.

Answer (score 0):

This might help with raising to the power of 2:

```
int answer = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    answer += x;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input, however the point of this recursive problem is to not use an iterative solution.